# Получить строку с регулярными выражениями

Tags: java, строки

Например есть строка:

```
String str = "text\ntext";
```

Если ее вывести:

```
System.out.printIn(str);
```

Вот что я получу:

```
text
text
```

Как вывести строку вот так?

```
text\ntext
```

Comment: Добавить `replace('\n','\\n')`

Comment: System.out.println(a.replace("\n", "\\\n")); Просто "" а не ''.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я Языках программирования и не только после знака `\` идут спецсимволы. `\n` - это символ новой строки. Поэтому, stdout показывает, следующее за этим символом строки, с новой строки. Для того, чтобы получить тот результат, который вам надо, вам необходимо экранировать знак `\`. Вам нужно исходный текст заменить на `text\\ntext`, либо перед выводом написать 
 `System.out.printIn(str.replace('\n','\\n'));` как написал [@nick-n-a](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17974/nick-n-a)